# AuthenticateFormsUser with no password

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I believe in SharePoint 2007 you could authenticate a user programatically (without a password) using something like this: 
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);

In SharePoint 2010 since FBA moved to claims we need to use something like this:
SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(site, username, password);

Is there an equivalent using SharePoint 2010 that you can use that does not require a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own custom membership and roles provider.  This allowed me to not have to use the default FBA configuration in SharePoint 2010 that now uses Claims.  This article got me started.  I then customized to meet my requirements.

http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/05/writing-a-custom-membership-provider-and-using-it-for-fba-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-from-the-scratch/

Comment: obautista I'm in the same situation and I already have my own custom membership provider can you tell me how you got it working with your custom provider? from what I can see the claims base authentication generally is like a wrapper around your custom provider. Even if you create a custom method within your custom provider, which doesn't require a password, how were you able to get the claim base authentication to call it and generate a valid token for it? I forgot to add that I need both the normal authentication method that require username and password and the one that doesn't require pass

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small confusion here.

The RedirectFromLoginPage method comes from System.Web.Security class, which is not a SharePoint class. So, you should be able to call this method even in SharePoint 2010 by specifying `using System.Web.Security`.

Moreover this method is not used for authenticating a user. It only redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default URL. The parameter username of this method should be an authenticated user. Check the [usage here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Whenever you call `RedirectFromLoginPage` method, you will be calling it inside the `Membership.ValidateUser(username,password)` method to authenticate the user first.

Using the method `SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser` would be preferable.

Comment: My apologies on the confusion.  Is there a way to programatically authenticate a user without requiring the password?

Answer (score -3):

You can check if anonymous access is enabled on

Please check this Site

http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.in/2011/05/check-if-anonymous-access-is-enabled.html

Comment: This answer does not really help with the scenario above. The question is how to authenticate users, not allow anonymous.